# How to handle an SQS event that's triggered by S3?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an S3 bucket that dispatches a message to an SQS queue whenever an object is added. That SQS queue in return triggers a Lambda which attempts to retrieve that recently added object using its key.

The `FunctionHandler` method in in my Lambda looks something like this:

```
public async Task FunctionHandler(S3EventNotification evnt, ILambdaContext context) {
    // evnt.Records[0].S3 is null
}
```

**Am I handling the right event here?** The reason I'm handling `S3EventNotification` is because when I inspected the messages inside the SQS queue, their contents corresponded to the `S3EventNotification` event type ([see documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TS3EventNotification.html)). Yet for some reason the properties I'm trying to access are null.

If I try to handle an `SQSEvent` instead, there's no way for me to get the object key which I need in order to be able to grab the corresponding object from my S3 bucket.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to handle an `SQSEvent` here. I believe in each `event.records` you will have the `body` property which will hold the original S3 event. It might need some serialisation.

Something like:

```
public class Function
{
    public string Handler(SQSEvent sqsEvent)
    {
        foreach (var record in sqsEvent.Records)
        {
            // record.Body has your S3 event
        }
    }
}
```

Out of interest, have you considered going straight from S3 -> EventBridge -> Lambda? That way you skip the SQS Queue.

Comment: Would the body property on the SQSEvent records contain an S3EventNotification or an S3Event? And I'm assuming that since body is a string, these events would be in raw JSON that needs serialization, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly if SQSEvent or S3EventNotification is what would be in the Body. Your best bet is to debug it and check. If you are struggling to debug it locally you could perhaps just log it to CloudWatch and see what the content is. I would imagine that you are correct and the string will need serialisation to the correct class.

Comment: @AlexBailey You are correct -- the S3 Event would be 'encapsulated' within the SQS Event as a string, which needs to be converted into a normal object. This can be avoided by going straight from the S3 Event to the AWS Lambda function.